# Laravel include(DatabaseSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4.30 in Windows10 with php 7.1.4 and composer 1.4.1.

When I execute

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I get these information

```
PS D:\data\new_site\test > php artisan db:seed


  [ErrorException]
  include(D:\data\new_site\test\vendor\composer/../../seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The path of `DatabaseSeeder.php` is

```
D:\data\new_site\test\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php
```

And the path of my Laravel folder is

```
D:\data\new_site\test
```

I had executed `composer dump-autoload` but it doesn't fix the problem.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved. It seems that it was the bug of composer. I upgrade my composer version from 1.4.1 to 1.5.2 and execute `composer dump-autoload`
Finally I can run seeder successfully.